# How to get attributes from a line of XML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have this line as a part from uml doc.

```
<children xmi:type="corstr:heighj" uml:name="private" x="255" y="188" width="221" height="51"/>
```

- I need the values for x,y width and height *

I tried with this function

```
function getValues(mainBlock, valueLine)   {


console.log("searching for data in " + valueLine)

console.log("x? " + getValueFromLine(valueLine, "x=\""));
console.log("y? " + getValueFromLine(valueLine, "y=\""));
console.log("width? " + getValueFromLine(valueLine, "width=\""));



function getValueFromLine(valueLine, searchFor)
{
    var position = valueLine.indexOf(searchFor);

    return valueLine.substr(position + searchFor.length, (valueLine.indexOf("\"", position + searchFor.length)) - position + searchFor.length);
}
```

but apparently something is wrong so I am getting this in the console

```
x? 255" y="1<br>
index1.html:179 y? 188" width<br>
index1.html:180 width? 221" height="51"/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are solutions out there but I've written a function that would help you out.

I've taken the approach of breaking down the strings and parsing the attributes separately, and to allow you to use the elements as per need - I've written a function as a closure to the given string.

It splits on **SPACE**, then I parsed the breakdowns and split on **EQUALS**, then parse integers if possible to finally create an object that contains the parsed values. A *helper function* to get you the specified value is enclosed in the function.

Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6yxb4es/) and let me know if you don't understand the code.

```
function parse_uml(valueLine) {
    var value_map = {};
    var breakdown = valueLine.split(" ");
    breakdown.shift();
    breakdown[breakdown.length - 1] = breakdown[breakdown.length - 1].substr(0, breakdown[breakdown.length - 1].length - 2);
    breakdown.map(function (i) {
        var attr = i.split("=");
        if (parseInt(attr[1].substr(1, attr[1].length - 2))) {
            value_map[attr[0]] = parseInt(attr[1].substr(1, attr[1].length - 2));
        } else {
            value_map[attr[0]] = attr[1].substr(1, attr[1].length - 2);
        }
    });
    return function (searchFor) {
        return value_map[searchFor];
    };
}
```

USAGE -

```
var parsed_uml = parse_uml('<children xmi:type="corstr:heighj" uml:name="private" x="255" y="188" width="221" height="51"/>', 'width');

console.log("Value of x - " + parsed_uml("x"));
console.log("Value of y - " + parsed_uml("y"));
console.log("Value of width - " + parsed_uml("width"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6yxb4es/

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had written an XML parser that i forked for you. This code converts a dom element to an object. May be the below code helps you to extract the attributes in a given XML tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/wyqm16k0/

```
 function parsethis(line){
  var x = line.split(" "), dom = x.shift(), obj;
  dom = dom.replace("<","");
  x[x.length-1] = x[x.length-1].replace("/>","");
  x.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    var str = '"'+array[index];
    str = str.replace('=','":');
    array[index] = str;
  });

  obj = x.join("");
  obj = "{"+obj.replace(/""/g,'","')+"}";
  obj = JSON.parse(obj);
  obj.dom = dom;
  return obj;
}

var parsed = parsethis('<children xmi:type="corstr:heighj" uml:name="private" x="255" y="188" width="221" height="51"/>');
console.log("X = "+parsed.x,", Y = "+parsed.y, ", Width = "+parsed.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse your whole document as an xml file, and then get your element like any other DOMElement, using its `getAttributeNS()` method.

Since I don't have the whole document, here is a proof of concept, after the non-declared xsi and uml's namespaces' attributes have been removed from the string :

```js
function cleanNS(input) {
  var str = input.split(' ');
  var cleaned = [];
  str.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.split('=')[0].indexOf(':') === -1) {
      cleaned.push(e);
    }
  });
  return cleaned.join(' ');
}

var parser = new DOMParser();

var cleanDoc = cleanNS('<children xmi:type="corstr:heighj" uml:name="private" x="255" y="188" width="221" height="51"/>');

var element = parser.parseFromString(cleanDoc, 'application/xml').documentElement;

function log(str) {
  document.body.innerHTML = str;
}
log("x = " + element.getAttributeNS(null, 'x') + ", y = " + element.getAttributeNS(null, 'y') + ", width = " + element.getAttributeNS(null, 'width'));
```